# guidance with floating aside boxes below nav bar on right

Tags: html, css

I am sorry if I am going over old ground, however I have searched and searched for a solution but am now ready to literally pull my hair out Arrgghh :(
You guys are my last resort. I pre-thank you 100 times :)

I want to position my side (aside) boxes to the top right side below the nav bar  on top of each other, rather than side by side, but cannot seem to do this. Please can you lovely people spot my code error or offer a solution.
Also, I want to keep things as simple as possible

HTML5 code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html lang="en-GB">

 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Care farm">
 <meta name="keywords" content="agriculture, dsiability, farm,     
     learning,         health, green care, outdoors, autism">
 <meta name="author" content="Dean xxxxx">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" title="Able  
 Farm" media="all">

<title>Care Farm</title>

</head>

<body class="body">

<header class="mainHeader">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">

    <nav><ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li> 
        <li><a href="care_farming.html">Care Farming</a></li> 
        <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li> 
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul></nav>
</header>

<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="content">
        <article class="topcontent">
            <header>
                <h2><a href="index.html" title="post">first post</a></h2>
            </header>

            <footer>
                <p class="post info">this post is written by dean</p>
            </footer>

            <content>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor s.</p>
            </content>
        </article>

        <article class="bottomcontent">
            <header>
        <h2><a href="index.html" title="second post">second   </a></h2>
            </header>

            <footer>
                <p class="post info">this post is written by dean</p>
            </footer>

            <content>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cdo eiusm.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a.</p>
            </content>
          </article>
      </div>
  </div>

    <aside class="top-sidebar">
    <article>
        <h2>top sidebar</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Excepteur cupidatat non proident, .</p>
    </article>
   </aside>

 <aside class="middle-sidebar">
    <article>
        <h2>middle sidebar</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit a fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </article>  
   </aside>

 <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
    <article>
        <h2>bottom sidebar</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doloe eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur.</p>
    </article>
   </aside>

    <footer class="mainFooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Dean King    
    </footer>

    </body>

   </html>
```

CSS3 code:

```
body {
background-image: url('../img/grass2.png');
color: #000305;
font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
font-size: 112.5%; /* base font size is 18px/13.5pt */
text-align: left;
line-height: 1.5;       
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {

}

a:hover, a:active {

}

.body {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
clear: both;
}

.mainHeader img {
width: 30%;
height: auto;
margin: 2%;
}

.mainHeader nav {
background-color: #666;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
float: left;
display: inline;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
color: #FFF;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 25px;
height: 20px; /* ajust height */
 }


 .mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
 .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
background-color: #CF5C3F;
text-shadow: none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a {
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 }

.mainContent {
line-height: 25px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
overflow:
}

.content {
width: 70%;
background-color:
float: left;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 }

.topcontent {
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 3% 5%;
margin-top: 2%;
 }

 .bottomcontent {
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 3% 5%;
margin-top: 2%;
 }

.top-sidebar {
width: 21%;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2% 3%;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
margin-top: 2%;
}

.middle-sidebar {
width: 21%;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2% 3%;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
}   

.bottom-sidebar {
width: 21%;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2% 3%;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
 }  

.mainFooter{
width: 100%;
float: left;
height: 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #666;
padding: 3% 5%;
margin-top: 2% 0;
 }

.mainFooter p {
width: 92%;
margin: 1% auto;
color: #FFF;
 }
```

Comment: One issue is that in your styles for `.content`, your `background-color` has no value, which means your next declaration (`float: left;`) doesn't get parsed. See below for a more complete answer.

Comment: Thank you.  Its great to have a new set of eyes on things.  You sir, are a bacon saver hehe!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is to:

- Surround your 3 `<aside>` elements with `<div class="sidebar">...</div>`
- float the `<div class="sidebar">` to the right
- float `<div class="content">` to the left

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
background-image: url('../img/grass2.png');
color: #000305;
font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
font-size: 112.5%; /* base font size is 18px/13.5pt */
text-align: left;
line-height: 1.5;       
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {

}

a:hover, a:active {

}

body {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
clear: both;
}

.mainHeader img {
width: 30%;
height: auto;
margin: 2%;
}

.mainHeader nav {
background-color: #666;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
float: left;
display: inline;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
color: #FFF;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 25px;
height: 20px; /* ajust height */
 }


 .mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active,
 .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
background-color: #CF5C3F;
text-shadow: none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a {
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 }

.mainContent {
line-height: 25px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
overflow:
}

.content {
float: left;
width: 70%;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 }

.topcontent {
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 3% 5%;
margin-top: 2%;
 }

 .bottomcontent {
background-color: #FFF;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 3% 5%;
margin-top: 2%;
 }

.top-sidebar {
background-color: #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2% 3%;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
margin-top: 2%;
}

.middle-sidebar {
background-color: #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2% 3%;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
}   

.bottom-sidebar {
background-color: #FFF;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 2% 3%;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-bottom: 2%;
 }  

.mainFooter{
width: 100%;
float: left;
height: 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #666;
padding: 3% 5%;
margin-top: 2% 0;
 }

.mainFooter p {
width: 92%;
margin: 1% auto;
color: #FFF;
 }

.sidebar {
display: block;
float: right;
width: 21%;
}
```

```html
<header class="mainHeader">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo">

    <nav><ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li> 
        <li><a href="care_farming.html">Care Farming</a></li> 
        <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li> 
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul></nav>
</header>

<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="content">
        <article class="topcontent">
            <header>
                <h2><a href="index.html" title="post">first post</a></h2>
            </header>

            <footer>
                <p class="post info">this post is written by dean</p>
            </footer>

            <content>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor s.</p>
            </content>
        </article>

        <article class="bottomcontent">
            <header>
        <h2><a href="index.html" title="second post">second   </a></h2>
            </header>

            <footer>
                <p class="post info">this post is written by dean</p>
            </footer>

            <content>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cdo eiusm.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a.</p>
            </content>
          </article>
      </div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <aside class="top-sidebar">
    <article>
        <h2>top sidebar</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Excepteur cupidatat non proident, .</p>
    </article>
   </aside>

 <aside class="middle-sidebar">
    <article>
        <h2>middle sidebar</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit a fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    </article>  
   </aside>

 <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
    <article>
        <h2>bottom sidebar</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum doloe eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur.</p>
    </article>
   </aside>
   </div>

  </div>

    <footer class="mainFooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Dean King    
    </footer>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  All working now.  HTML and CSS is such interesting areas, but wow can be frustrating when things dont go right lol!